# How to underline a Container Widget in Flutter

Tags: widget, flutter, underline

I am trying to underline a Container in my Flutter app. So far I achieved a some kind of underling when I used the following code:

```
    Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Underline my parent!',
                  maxLines: 2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        decoration: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
      ),
```

But now I want the underline dash not being from start to end, I want to have space on the start and on the end. If there is some smarter way to underline widgets I would be glad to see it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple `Divider` widget including a padding:

```
new Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
    child: new Divider()
),
```

You can then wrap your existing widget with a column:

```
new Column(
    children: <Widget> [
        yourContainerWidget,
        new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
            child: new Divider()
        ),     
    ]
)
```

Comment: Ok, but where should go this Divider? After Container?

Comment: It is a quite good approach, but I can not set the divider width now.

Comment: Then try to remove the padding around it.

Comment: I mean width of underling dash, now it is fixed pixels, I do not see any possibility to make it's width for example 5 pixels

Comment: Well, you could put it in a Container and set the width with the `width` property.

Answer (score 26):

Add a bottom `BorderSide` to your container.

```
     Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
           border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
           ),
       ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply to create underline in Container widget using `Border`

here the code:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(
        width: 1.0
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Underline my parent!',
    maxLines: 2,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to create a line using `Container` widget. And wrap Row widget using a Column widget and add that line as the second child, like below:

```
var aLine = Container(color: Colors.grey, width: 50.0, height: 2.0,); 

Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Underline my parent!',
                maxLines: 2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      aLine
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

User this `const Divider(color: Colors.black54),`

Comment: What kind of value adds your answer more then the accepted answer given by Bostrot?